# How to enable Kid's corner in windows 10 mobile?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, settings, kids-corner

I was using kid's corner settings in windows phone 8.1 but since I have upgraded I can't found that setting anymore. I have tried :

- Searching in Settings' search box.
- Manually gone under every heading of settings.
- Rebooting and resetting my phone.

But there is no outcome. So, Is there any trick to enable kid's corner in Windows 10 mobile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can tell, Kids Corner has been removed. However, it seems to have been replaced with Apps Corner, which essentially does the same thing, and can be found under Accounts in Settings.

Comment: But don't get too used to it. App Corner will be removed with the Windows 10 Creators Update comming in ~Q2

Comment: Apps corner from kids corner and it will also be removed..........I can't understand what Microsoft is doing.